# Load content into a div onclick - FadeOut(), FadeIn()

Tags: jquery, fadein, fade, fadeout

I have a simple menu with `<ul>`s. Every `<ul>` loads its content into a `<div>` on clicking it.

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/EPvGf/16

So to be able to understand my problem, when you first open the page try to click any `<ul>` (instead of the default one "description"). You can see the content that should be loaded (faded in) goes under the content that was before it and when the old content finishes fading out the new content that fades in goes up to take the old content's place.

What I want is that when the old content **FULLY** disappears off the page, the new content appears in its place and **not** under each other then one gets the place of the second.

Comment: I edited the jsfiddle URL..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where you need to make use of the complete callback in the fadeout method:

```
$('.pbox:visible').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('.pbox[id=' + $this.data('id') + ']').fadeIn('slow'); //After everything has been faded out fade in the corresponding div.
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NFwdu/)

Plus you may want to add this on document ready

```
 $('.pbox:gt(0)').hide();  // hide everything but the first one first up.
```

and  get rid of

```
.find('a:first').click();
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u4Yfj/)

Comment: I agree, your solution is a bit more solid than mine :-) +1

Comment: @PSL Do you have any experience with ebay? I mean, I have some problem with really small functional things and css on ebay, it's not from codes it's from ebay listing, if you have some please tell me I would like to make a small deal with you :-)

Comment: @PSL I sent you a message to your email, could you please take a look on it?, thank you

Comment: @user2401856 Cool. Can't access mail at office.. so anyways got fixed.. Good.. :)

Answer (score 4):

By running a function on complete of the .pbox:visible fadeOut you can fade in the new div (or run any other code you want).

```
$('.pbox:visible').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('.pbox[id=' + $('.current a').attr('data-id') + ']').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EPvGf/20/

Comment: Welcome to SO and good try too... +1... :) Just add an explanation on why you want to make this change.

Answer (score 2):

One solution:

Use the delay to wait until after the fade out is finished. you may need to play with the number

```
$('.pbox[id=' + $(this).attr('data-id') + ']').delay(800).fadeIn('slow');
```

Comment: @SethMcClaine You got my +1 too. Because it was a good try.. :)